# Public Key pinning with X509TrustManagerExtensions checkServerTrusted

Tags: android, x509, tls1.2, trustmanager, public-key-pinning

**Public key pinning in for a HTTPS TLS connection.**

There is an issue with Android API, below 17, that enables MITM (Man in the Middle) attack incase of public key pinning. This has been explained in the link below.

https://www.cigital.com/blog/ineffective-certificate-pinning-implementations/

So in Android minimum sdk below 17, ie, below Android version 4.2, we need to initialise the **X509TrustManager** with Android Keystore which has only the server root certificates (*instead of the default keystore; which would have all certificates installed in the device*). This helps in cleaning the leaf certificates received from the server before performing public key pinning.

From Android API 17 onwards, Android has introduced **X509TrustManagerExtensions** which performs this root cleaning at OS level.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/X509TrustManagerExtensions.html

**My question:**

I would be glad if anyone could please provide an example on how to implement the following method provided by the X509TrustManagerExtensions for root cleaning.

```
List<X509Certificate> checkServerTrusted (X509Certificate[] chain, 
                String authType, 
                String host)
```

I am confused with the following.

1. `host`; should it be the domain URL? with https or without? or should it be the full url (domain + relative path)
2. How to create instant of a `X509TrustManagerExtensions`?
   The constructor for X509TrustManagerExtensions takes `X509TrustManager` as input. Do we create this X509TrustManager with the android default keystore?

**Code snippet (Not working):**

```
   TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
   tmf.init(KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()));

   for (TrustManager trustManager : tmf.getTrustManagers()) {
       X509TrustManagerExtensions tme = new X509TrustManagerExtensions((X509TrustManager) trustManager);
       tme.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType, <<String https://www.example.com>>);
   }
```

**Exception:**
Trust anchor for certification path not found

**Possible security risk:**
Using `KeyStore.getDefaultType()`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use >= API 17?

Comment: 'X509TrustManagerExtensions' exists only from API 17 and above.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to get hold of the trust manager by using the `TrustManagerFactory`. When initialising this you pass in null for it to use the default `Keystore` and it will return the default trust managers. With this you can then create the `X509TrustManagerExtensions` using the first `X509TrustManager`.

```
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
        TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);

// Find first X509TrustManager in the TrustManagerFactory
X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = null;
for (TrustManager trustManager : trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()) {
    if (trustManager instanceof X509TrustManager) {
        x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManager;
        break;
    }
}

X509TrustManagerExtensions x509TrustManagerExtensions = 
        new X509TrustManagerExtensions(trustManager());
```

Then to execute this the host I've successfully used just the domain part:

```
List<X509Certificate> trustedCerts = x509TrustManagerExtensions
        .checkServerTrusted(untrustedCerts, "RSA", "appmattus.com");
```

For those using `HttpUrlConnection` the the untrusted certs is determined with:

```
Certificate[] serverCerts = ((HttpsUrlConnection)conn).getServerCertificates();
X509Certificate[] untrustedCerts = Arrays.copyOf(serverCerts, 
        serverCerts.length, 
        X509Certificate[].class);
```

If you are using OkHttp then you can just use the built in [CertificatePinner](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS#certificate-pinning) that has since been updated to fix the issues mentioned in that article.

Comment: and what is `trustManager()` method?